# Trying to get the old age level of a person from family dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to get the old age level of a person from this dictionary:

```
d = {'Sıdıka': [{'Aziz': [{'Ahmet': [{'Kuzey': []}]}, {'Öznur': [{'Elif': []}, {'Yiğit': []}]}, {'İlknur': [{'Nurullah': []}, {'Büşra': []}]}, {'İlker': [{'Melih': []}]}]}]}
```

"Sıdıka" is the eldest one and I want to determine her level (which is 3 (Ex. "Sıdıka" is "Kuzey"'s
father's, father's, mother. Which makes 3)).

How can i achieve that?

I tried:
Recursion, but couldn't figure it out how.

My attempt:

```
def new(self,dict,count,max):
        for i in dict:
            print(dict[i])
            if len(dict[i])!=0:
                for i in dict[i]:
                    self.new(self,i,count,max)
                    count+=1
                    print(count)
            else:
                return count
```

Comment: Could you post your attempt?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark posted to edit

Comment: The logic is unclear, do you need to specify both the ancestor and the final child as input? Or do you want the max?

Comment: @mozway i just want the max. I think i got the answer

Comment: Why do you store it with lists? You can just use the dictionaries and `None` whenever there is no child node after it. Example: `{'ancestor': {'child1': {'lastchild': None}, 'child2': None}}`

Comment: @Eric I was also wondering ;)

Comment: @EricJin even when i do that, question still remains (level of person in family tree) (thank you for the suggestion though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple recursion in one statement (assuming `d` the input dictionary).

You can uncomment the print to see how it works.

```
def level(d, lvl=0):
    #print(f'level {lvl}:', d)
    return max((lvl, *(level(l, lvl=lvl+1)
                       for v in d.values()
                       for l in v)
               ))

level(d)
```

Output: `3`

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the solution:

```
self.max_= 0
def new(self,dict,count):
        for i in dict:
            print(dict[i])
            if len(dict[i])!=0:
                for i in dict[i]:
                    print(self.max_)
                    self.new(self,i,count)
                    count+=1
                    # print(count)
            else:
                if count>self.max_:
                    self.max_=count
        return self.max_
```